# Container App Environment creation timing out

Tags: azure-devops, terraform, azure-pipelines, azure-container-apps, azapi

Where I work has just started migrating to the cloud. We've successfully deployed a number of resources using Terraform and Pipelines into Azure.

Where we are running into issues is deploying a Container App Environment, we have code that was working in a less locked down environment (setup for Proof of Concept), but are now having issues using that code in our go-forward.

When deploying, the Container App Environment spends 30mins attempting to create before it returns a context deadline exceeded error. Looking in Azure Portal, I can see the resource in "Waiting" provisioning state and I can also see the MC_ and AKS resources that get generated. It then fails around 4hrs later.

Any advice?

I am suspecting it's related to security on the Virtual Network that the subnets are sitting on, but I'm not seeing any logs on the deployment to confirm. The original subnets had a Network Security Group (NSG) assigned and I configured the rules that Microsoft provide before I added a couple of subnets without an NSG assigned and no luck.

My next step is to try provisioning it via the GUI and see if that works.

Comment: I would try the UI first, make sure everything works as expected, then you can always run a terraform plan to see what drift (if any) happens after terraform importing your resources (that way your real config is stored in state and terraform will diff your actual code against state then tell you what the diff is). https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/cli/import

There are timeout values here if that's of interest too: https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/plugin/sdkv2/resources/retries-and-customizable-timeouts

Comment: Hi ,glad to know you've found the solution to resolve this issue! Please consider accepting it as an answer to change its status to Answered. See [can I answer my own question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer), Just a reminder :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I managed to break our build in the "anything goes" environment.

The root cause is an incomplete configuration of the Virtual Network which has custom DNS entries. This has now been passed to our network architects to resolve. If I can get more details on the fix they apply I'll include that here for anyone else that runs into the issue.